# Please make tags and meta tags visually different on meta and main

Tags: feature-request, tags

Now there is no visual distinction between [bug](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) **when used in comments**, even if proper markup is applied ( `[tag:bug] and [meta-tag:bug]`).

Even worse with [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) and [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) - on my browser (Firefox on Android and on Windows 10) I can't see any difference **even in question**.

Both result with :

```
<a class="post-tag" rel="tag"
```

So there can't be any difference in how they look, right?

Please make them visually different, so that in case of doubt it would be clearly visible if it's a tag or meta tag.

---

A little Tampermonkey script, if anyone's interested:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         MetaTag
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  Make meta tags distinct
// @author       Mołot
// @match        http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    GM_addStyle("a.meta-tag::before  { color: #aaa; content: 'meta-tag:'}");
    $('a[href^="http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/"]').addClass("meta-tag");
    $('a[href*="/tagged/"]').addClass("meta-tag");
    $('a[href^="https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/"]').removeClass("meta-tag");
})();
```

Comment: Why do we have a "bug" tag on main?  Surely it should be "bugs"?

Comment: It was only an example, taken from http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4624/809

Comment: @Mołot Is this something we even have the power/authority to do?

Comment: @James a few of my requests, similar in scope, was implemented. True, I asked them on network-wide meta. But I don't know if it's really a network wide need, so this one I posted here. Yes, changing minor aspects of appearance can be requested successfully. It depends a lot on the votes on this question.

Comment: You should say what browser you are using, etc. I use both firefox and chrome on a desktop (on Ubuntu) and I can clearly see the difference between the tags you have in your post.

Comment: @kingelodion in comments as well?

Comment: @kingledion see my edit - I'm really interested how can you see any difference between hard sciences in question - if that's what you meant.

Comment: In comments links are just links; tags aren't specially styled there.  So if the same tag exists on main and meta, you won't be able to tell in a comment except by inspecting the target URL.  I suggest you limit this request to posts, which are styled and could therefore be styled differently.

Comment: @Molot Ok, my browser highlighted the main page 'hard-science' tag text with an 'already clicked link' color. Now that I have visited both tag pages, they look the same. However, for the 'bug' tags, the meta tag is a darker shade of grey, so those are distinguishable.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I came from [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/mołot), where adding a class to link generated from tag is trivial. I hope Stack Exchange software is similarly flexible. Also, in modern browsers [you can style link by destination only](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-links-depending-on-destination/) so I don't think it should be that hard?

Comment: I see the bugs as two different shades of grey but the hard-science tags have the same colour in my firefox (desktop) - while I can tell them apart when they are next to each other, I would prefer if they were more distinct as I might not consider a minor shading difference when seeing the tags alone in text. I'm all for it.

Comment: @Mrkvička the bugs are different because the four special meta tags -- discussion, bug, support, and feature-request -- are styled differently in posts and the tags list.